# How to display jQuery content inside form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to make an instant search in a form, so when i start typing in the "brand" input field, suggested terms should appear bellow (from the database where i have several brand names).
This is working outside the form but not inside...

Here's the form:

```
<script id="blockOfStuff" name="blockOfStuff" language="text">

<form name="add_device" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addproduct.php?add=1" method="POST">
<div id="field">Brand: <input type="text" name="brand"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</script>
```

The form is inside the script tag because i need to make it visible on button click:

The instant search is made with jQuery like this:

```
<?php

$content ='<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="service.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
        $(".search").keyup(function() {
                var searchid = $(this).val();
                var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
                if (searchid != \'\') {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "searchbrand.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html) {
                                $("#result").html(html);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });

            jQuery("#result").on("click", function(e) {
                    var $clicked = $(e.target);
                    var $name = $clicked.find(\'.name\').html();
                        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text(); $(\'#searchid\').val(decoded);
                        });

                    jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) {
                        var $clicked = $(e.target);
                        if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
                            jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
                    $(\'#searchid\').click(function(){
                        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
                    });
            });


</script>

<input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Cauta brand" />
<div id="result"></div>
';

?>

<?php echo $content; ?> // this works outside the form but not inside...
```

the reading from database is made in searchbrand.php where the line looks like this:

```
echo'       <div class="show" align="left" >
                <img src="http://10i.ro/images/arrow.png" style="height:15px; float:left; margin-right:2px;" /><span class="name">'.$final_brand.'</span>
            </div>';
```

I'm sorry i was so long by i needed to show you all the connections.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot use stuff like that inside `<script>` tags. That's wrong! Dot.

Comment: You can use jquery functions like : onchange of the that input box, and perform your jquery action there

Comment: @PraveenKumar i know is not really ok but the form is large and it was the most convenient solution, as the time was short to think at something else. How about the question? How do i display the result from jQuery to the form?

Comment: @Nehal can you teach me to do that?

Comment: @chitoiudaniel Please explain in brief what you want to be done, and I'll give you the exact possible solution for it

Comment: @Nehal  I want to use the "brand" input field as instant search field for the brand names from database. Now it is working if i use the "searchid" input field and "result" display div, but only outside the form. I need it to work somehow inside "add_device" form. Thanks!

Comment: You've used the <form> tag in <script> tags, I'm sorry, but this is not possible why you want to do something like this. Is it not possible without this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97192/discussion-between-nehal-and-chitoiu-daniel).

Comment: @PraveenKumar If i replace the <script> tag with <div> tag, i have an onclick event calling a javascipt function that is not working anymore, and i don't know why. The function is outside the form, at the beginning of the code between <script> tags.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with hot search is about how much network requests you can do while the user is typing. Don't try to be like Google in this case ok, try to be more simple.

1. Fetch some of most wanted results from the server, if you don't have much results on server side, bring all then at once.
2. Save on client side, your previous requests in a 1 level array like this:

`["Art", "Baby", "Cat", "Doge"]`

3. Now you are ready to show results instantly, use the [Fuse Search](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse) on client side fro this.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, instead to write tags that you need to display dynamically on page inside `<script>` tag, why not you write semantically inside `<body>`?

Is much more easy if you separate these concepts instead to mix tags with script :)

Look, is semantically correct to keep your html elements inside `<body>` and use `<script>` tag to host script always, even your tags are dynamically created, changed or removed by events or actions handled on javascript.

Just get access to dom object you want to modify and have a fun!

I hope this tips can help you.

Comment: i don't have a problem with search. It is working well outside the form. I need to make it work inside the form. It's a matter of displaying the result. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess the [Fuse Search demo page](http://kiro.me/exp/fuse.html) has what you need, let me know if this help you.

Comment: Thanks Jan, but it doesn't really help me. I need to understand why i can't display the result inside my <script> tag, but it works outside...

Comment: Cool, so please check my answer again, I've updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was the `<script>` tag containing the form, though I didn't understand why... I've changed script tag into div tag and now it's fine.
Thanks all!

Comment: Because <script> elements can only contain script, not other html elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this jQuery plugin. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10470188)

Comment: I'll just edit my answer and add the code. Thanks for informing me.